# How do I dynamically change the, "cannot be blank parameter" with logic based on paramters

Tags: infopath, list-form

I am creating a form for a SharePoint office 365 site. I have enough knowledge of Info-path and Sharepoint to make them work together. What I am trying to do is to make a required field not required anymore.

[image: Example]

In this example I have a radio box and input field called, "your name required" that is required field. I want it so that if option 3 is clicked, then "your name required" is no longer required. How do you do that or is it even possible. If it is not possible, what is the next best solution?